# Man page based on package name?

Tags: apt, manpage

I have a script that gets man pages based on a package name. Most of the time this works:

```sh
...
# get program description for each
xargs man -f | grep \(1\) | sed 's/(1)//g' |
...
```

I'm looking for a solution that will also work with packages that have man pages which aren't located under the package name.

For example, if my list of packages to install includes `python-pip`, which requires `man pip`.

*Thus, I need to either automated getting the command e.g., `pip` from `python-pip`, but a solution that works for all cases. Or somehow get a man page via package name directly.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get manpages from a package, check the list of files for files in `/usr/share/man`:

```
$ dpkg -L python-pip | grep 'man[0-8].*/'
/usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pip2.1.gz
$ dpkg -L deja-dup | grep 'man[0-8].*/'
/usr/share/man/az/man1/deja-dup-preferences.1.gz
/usr/share/man/az/man1/deja-dup.1.gz
/usr/share/man/lv/man1/deja-dup-preferences.1.gz
/usr/share/man/lv/man1/deja-dup.1.gz
/usr/share/man/sr/man1/deja-dup-preferences.1.gz
```

Comment: like this? man -w python-pip

Comment: The list of programs I have is based on names in apt. So I would need to automate getting pip from python-pip for all possible cases where apt name is not command name.

Comment: You want manpages from a package or packages from manpages?

Comment: I want to get the man page associated with an apt package. For example man python-pip (though this doesn't seem to be possible directly).

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride see update